# What is the voltage drop across the 10 ohm resistor?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, voltage, mesh-analysis

[image: Circuit]

What is the voltage drop (V1) across the 10 ohm resistor?

Can I use voltage division to get V1?

Like V1 = (20 V x 10 Ω) / (10 Ω + 4 Ω)

But when I use nodal analysis and mesh analysis I get a different answer (12.30 V).

Which one should I use?

Or have I understood the voltage division method incorrectly?

Comment: I would go with superposition.

Comment: Can't I use voltage division here? 
Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm kinda amateur.

Comment: Use the method that you know to be true and don't guess at methods.

Comment: Voltage division will come into it, but do you understand how to use superposition to analyze a circuit like this?  If you don't understand superposition, that is ok, just ask!

Comment: I haven't solved much problems using Superposition theorem. But I just know the basic principle associated with it. So, how can I use superposition in this problem?

Comment: Well, you haven't got the right answer for nodal analysis either. You are 0.5 volts out. So, if you are as good at solving it in superposition as you are in nodal then you are not going to get there.

Comment: @RakshithKrish You only need the basic principle of it.  Replace one voltage source with a short, figure out the voltages...then do the same for the other source...then add them up.

Comment: @Andyaka Are you sure about this 0.5V?  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F10+%2B+%28x+-+20%29%2F4+%2B+%28x+-10%29%2F%2810%2F3%29+%3D+0+

Comment: I get the same answer for both nodal and mesh analysis V1 = 12.3076V

Comment: By using superposition I get 100/13 when 10V is closed and 60/13 when 20V is closed. After adding them up I get 160/13=12.3076V.
Even using superposition I get the same answer. @Andyaka

Comment: OK I was wrong in my calculation. Reality check!!

Comment: So, is it not possible to calculate directly using voltage division?

Comment: Only if we use a superposition than you can use a voltage divider equation.

Comment: I got the 12.3V answer using a 3rd method: use Thevenin to convert the 10V, 10||5=3.3, 10 Ohm into a single voltage source and resistance. Then you have a simple resistor divider between that and the 4 Ohm, 20V source.

Comment: As others have pointed out (but you don't seem to have fully understood) you need to use the superposition principle to find the contributions of each source and then add them together. This is really as basic as homework questions get, so I don't feel that there is justification for writing up an answer on EE.SE, instead go learn this from one of the literally thousands and thousands of freely available learning resources online.

Comment: [Millmans theorem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525733/how-to-solve-this-problem-in-the-simplest-way-via-ltspice/525736#525736) is a kind of voltage divider rule but the 3rd voltage is 0 volts (as feeding the bottom of the middle 10 ohm resistor). So, go to the link and try that method.

Comment: Why waste our time showing us 2 resistors in parallel?  The 10 ohm resistor has a conductance of 0.1 siemens, the 5 ohm resistor is 0.2 siemens, add up the conductances and get 0.3 siemens... so the resistance is 1/0.3.  Just replace it with 1 resistor of that value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Millman's theorem](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/millmans-theorem/) is a kind of multi source voltage divider theorem based on this topology: -

[image]
[image]

So, re-arrange your circuit to use a 3rd source that is actually 0 volts and you're good to go: -

[image]

Hence \$V_{AB} = \dfrac{\frac{10}{3.33333} + \frac{0}{10} +\frac{20}{4}}{\frac{1}{3.3333}+ \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{4}} = \dfrac{8}{0.65} = 12.3077\$

But equally, without working out the parallel resistance of the 10 Ω and 5 Ω you could have written this (now there are two sources of 10 volts, one in series with 10 Ω and one in series with 5 Ω): -

$$V_{AB} = \dfrac{\frac{10}{10} +\frac{10}{5} + \frac{0}{10} +\frac{20}{4}}{\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{4}} = \dfrac{8}{0.65} = 12.3077$$

Comment: +1 for the use of Millman's. Not enough people are aware of this simple approach

Comment: Not even as simple as it could be.  Working with resistance is awkward here.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't follow your comment. Could it be simpler - is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Andyaka I mean Millman's theory gets simpler when you work in conductance instead of resistance.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica isn't that what the denominator actually is? Sorry I'm not getting really what you mean here?

Answer (score 8):

Two voltage sources are contributing towards the voltage drop across V1.

So the equation \$V_1 = (20 .10)/(10+4)\$ is not correct. You ignored the 10V Source, and the 10 ohm-5 ohm resistor network in the process, as if they never exist in the circuit. Which is wrong.

Well, still 'voltage-division method' is what you use in superposition.

[image]

We have two voltage sources. Consider one voltage source at a time. Ideal voltage sources can be considered as a short or 0 ohm resistor, so short the other voltage source. Derive the two circuits.

Now, you can apply your voltage-divider formula on both circuits to calculate V1 on both cases. Finally, add them to get the net effect of both voltage sources. Thus, the net voltage drop V1.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this with either mesh or node analysis.

Here's my take on the problem using mesh analysis:

- Let’s call the left mesh Mesh I and the mesh on the right, Mesh II.
- There is a current i1 passing through Mesh I and a current i2 passing through Mesh II.
- Notice that both i1 and i2 pass through the 10 ohm resistor in the middle.

We can build a linear system of equations of the form:

{ 3.3333333 Ω * i1 + 10 Ω * (i1 + i2) = 10 V

{ 10 Ω * (i1 + i2) + 4 Ω * i2 = 20 V

After we find values for i1 and i2, we have: V1 = 10 Ω * (i1 + i2) from Ohm's law.

Here's the MATLAB solution:

```
A = [13.3333333333333, 10; 10, 14];
   
B = [10; 20];

I = linsolve(A, B);

V = 10 * (I(1) + I(2))
```

Hence: `V` = 12.3077

Comment: It is better to have the equations all symbolic and only use the actual values at the last moment.

Answer (score 5):

OK I got my initial calculation wrong but here's the source transformation method (answer now deleted because I was too hasty with my calculations). I've decided to undelete it because there is an accepted answer and the visibility of this answer makes a nice comparison.

Using source transformations: -

[image]

That's a total current of 8.0 amps flowing into a resistor of parallel values: -

$$R_P = \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{10} +\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{4}} = 1.5385 \Omega$$

So, the voltage is 8.0 amps x 1.5385 Ω = 12.308 volts.

Comment: Notice that 10Ω||5Ω  = 10Ω/3 and the current is I = 10V/(10Ω/3) = 3A

Comment: Oops yes. Fixing

Answer (score 4):

Let me give another approach, maybe simplistic.

There are several theorems or methods, but let's not forget that all those theorems come from the observation, someone found a pattern and proved its correctness.

However, when you are in front of a circuit like this, that is quite simple. Before applying theorems I think it is better to think by yourself.

Then, the first thing I see in this circuit is a parallel of two resistors that looks are there to confuse or to raise doubts, but I need to not be afraid and replace that parallel as follows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWWHql.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then you get the following circuit where you want to find V1 and if you observe it you can see that there are three currents involved in it, Ie flowing through the equivalent parallel resistor, I2 flowing through R2 and I1 flowing through R1. You also know from [Kirchoff's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) (and this a *law*, not a *theorem*) that I1 = Ie + I2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDdjUk.png)</sup>

Each current's value is the following:

$$I_e=\frac{V_a-V_1}{R_e}$$
$$I_2=\frac{V_b-V_1}{R_2}$$
$$I_1=\frac{V_1}{R_1}$$

With a bit of algebra you reach your V1 = 12.3077 volt

Comment: It would be better to use subscripts for those quantities, e.g. Va. We have [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on this platform (and HTML <sub></sub> as the poor man's version).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thanks for the comment, I am still learning the tools in here. Fully agree with this MathJax the readability increases