# How can we calculate V2 by nodal analysis in the following circuit?

Tags: nodal-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

How can we arrange it or solve by nodal analysis.

Comment: You know \$V_1\$ and \$V_3\$ -- they are defined by the voltage sources shown. You know that the \$9\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor does ***not*** change those, too. It's not even relevant.  The only question you have is, "What's \$V_2\$, given three surrounding voltages?" That's really simple:$$V_2=\frac{V_1\cdot 6\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega+V_3\cdot 6\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega+ 0\:\text{V}\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega}{6\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega+6\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega+12\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 12\:\text{k}\Omega}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have identified the nodes correctly. The next step would be to apply KCL considering anyone node at a time. If you observe the circuit, you will find that you have to determine the voltage V2 alone. Find the currents entering and leaving the junction using KCL and you'd be there.

Answer (score 0):

**Help without a solution**

> *How can we arrange it or solve by nodal analysis.*

Well you can certainly "arrange" it to be simpler because the 9 kΩ resistor plays no part in "making" V2. Then, if you know Millman's theorem, it's an easy solve.

Or, once you have discarded the 9 kΩ resistor, convert each voltage source and its associated series resistor to a current source. Then you'll have two parallel current sources and three parallel resistor. Converting to current sources is part of the proof of Millman's theorem.

It's an easy solve: -

[image]
[image]

Pictures from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525733/how-to-solve-this-problem-in-the-simplest-way-via-ltspice/525736#525736).